# Aurelia.js Change text value when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I can change the button color when this is clicked, but how can I change the text when is clicked too?

change text from **click** to **clicked**

**Html**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn ${clicked ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-primary'}" click.trigger="handleClick()">Click</button>
```

**JS**
...

```
  clicked = false;

  handleClick(){
    this.clicked = !this.clicked; // toggle clicked true/false
    return true; // only needed if you want to cancel preventDefault()
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the same with the text in the button that you did with the class:

```
<button type="button" class="btn ${clicked ? 'btn-danger' : 'btn-primary'}" click.trigger="handleClick()">
    ${clicked ? 'Clicked' : 'Click'}
</button>
```

Either that, or setting the button text to a variable, and changing it in the `handleClick` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can access element by using [ref](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/framework/latest/cheat-sheet/5) attribute. Also it is suggested to use `.delegate` instead of `.trigger` whenever possible. See more info [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-delegate-vs-trigger/1).

**Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=99524bb7fee9d0b7272741477c1fffb8**

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <button ref="btn" click.delegate="onClick(btn)">Click Me!</button>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  message = 'Hello World!';
  onClick(button) {
    button.innerText = 'Clicked!'
  }
}
```

**index.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Aurelia</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body aurelia-app>
    <h1>Loading...</h1>

    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/node_modules/requirejs/require.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/bundles/aurelia.js"></script>
    <script src="https://jdanyow.github.io/rjs-bundle/bundles/babel.js"></script>
    <script>
      require(['aurelia-bootstrapper']);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```